# How to store API-Url so that i can change easy in dist-folder

Tags: angular, api

I need to store my api-url not hard-coded in my angularproject. 
Following case i try to build:
After building my angular app with ng --build i will give the dist folder to my customer. The Angular app is one part of the package the customer have to host on his server. The other part is an .net core api.

My problem is that the api-url could be different for each customer. So i need an easy way to change this url in the dist folder. Something like an api-config.js file.

Whats the best way to serve this?

Comment: you can create a setup part for your app and set the API-URL dynamically from UI.

Comment: That would be great. But how do I store the settings? When I am in the setup part there is no connection to a database?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the API Url you typed in UI to make your first request as super-admin and because you are super admin and you are setting up the project so you don't need to log in first. your first setup (adding API-Url ) will be saved in DB and after that, you can check if there is an API-Url so skip setup part and redirect it to the login page.